# image permissions (don't want them in gallery)

Tags: android, image

I'm working on a application which stores its images in the Android/data folder.
The pictures are visible in the gallery, but I don't want that.

Is it possible to set permissions on a folder so they can only be used by the application itself, or should I just store them in another folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file called `.nomedia` in the folder. That'll hide them from the gallery application.

Here's how to do it in Java code:

```
File nomedia = new File(dataFolder, ".nomedia");
try {
    nomedia.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```